# Use an id on a button to update_post_meta in post

Tags: post-meta

I hope that someone can answer this conundrum for me.. As its doing my head in a bit LOL.

I have a button with the code as follows:

```
    <button class="contact-owner-send" id="rsvp_button">RSVP</button>
```

This button sends an email from a form within the system to the post owner. What I have is a custom field called "number_attending", this is within the posts in the back end.

When the user clicks the send button I want the number_attending field to be incremented up by one point.

I currently am using the following code, but it just doesn't seem to do what I want.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button#rsvp_button').click(function qwe4_tracker(){
    global $post;
        // get each post by ID
        $postID = $post->ID;
        // get the post's custom fields
        $custom = get_post_custom($postID);
        // find the view count field
        $views = intval($custom['number_attending'][0]);
        // increment the count
        if($views > 0) {
            update_post_meta($postID, 'number_attending', ($views + 1));
        } else {
            add_post_meta($postID, 'number_attending', 1, true);
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

I'm hoping someone can help me figure this one out :)

Comment: You have mixed PHP and Javascript in a way that is not going to work. Look up "AJAX API" in the Codex and on this site. Also look up "NoConflict".

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? I've been looking at this for far too long LOL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@s_ha_dum** has stated, your syntax mixes JS and PHP; and Ajax wil be needed.  I'll try to point you in the correct direction.

This should be your javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('button#rsvp_button').click(function qwe4_tracker(){

        var data = { action: 'my_action' };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);  // Uncomment to use for testing
        });
    });
});
```

NOTES:

1. We use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` to begin our JS.  This is to prevent clashes when using the global `$` jQuery variable.
2. The var `data` contains the `action`; which must be used in the PHP `add_action` described below.

And this should be your PHP function to handle the AJAX:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {

    global $post;  // You still may need to pass the POST ID here from the JS ajax.
    // get each post by ID
    $postID = $post->ID;
    // get the post's custom fields
    $custom = get_post_custom($postID);
    // find the view count field
    $views = intval($custom['number_attending'][0]);
    // increment the count
    if($views > 0) {
        update_post_meta($postID, 'number_attending', ($views + 1));
    } else {
        add_post_meta($postID, 'number_attending', 1, true);
    }
    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

The PHP function will handle the updating of the number in the post meta.. and the JS tells the PHP (via ajax) to update when the button is clicked.

NOTE:

You may still have an issue getting the proper Post ID.  If so, then you are going to need to declare this in a global JS variable via your PHP code.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Thank for putting nice article. I have a somewhat similar situation where I'm loading saved carts in woocommerce using the save&share cart plugin, I have created a page to load the cart titles and set cookies to get the cart name and ID saved to use them in the cart.php page. Is it possible to create a post update button in cart page using the post ID? save&share cart used CPT to save the carts basically I want to update the post when item added or delete.